# Broadcasting single message using APNS

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications, broadcast

I have an IOS app and JAVA on my server. I need to send only a single message to multiple device on same time. Is it possible via APNS(is there any service provided by apns, i didn't find). It will be impossible me to loop for every token because it will take time for every push as push must be on same time to all device tokens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have no alternative to iterating over the tokens and sending a message for each token. Even if you had such an alternative, and you could deliver all the device tokens at the same type to the APNS servers, the APNS servers would still have to send the message to all those tokens, which would take time.

The best you can do is use multiple threads, each having its own connection to APNS servers, and split the device tokens among them. That's the fastest way to deliver a large number of messages (regardless of whether they all have the same content or not) to Apple.

Comment: We could at least save some bandwidth toward the APNS server (which would be interest for apple too), if we could specify multiple tokens for a single payload. I have a feeling that this is a very common scenario.